# Disable Spell checker on Check In comments while publishing pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing-page

My requirement is to disable the spell checker on Version Comments field while I am publishing the SharePoint page.

I have tried the following:

1) In the page layout wrap your contact field with the following div

```
<div id="excludeContentFromSpellCheck">
   [FORM FIELD HERE]
   ...
</div>
```

2) Next step is to add the following JavaScript at the top of your PlaceHolderMain

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
    var a = document.getElementById('excludeContentFromSpellCheck');

    var b = a.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
          b[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
    }

    var c= a.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {
          c[i].setAttribute("excludeFromSpellCheck", "true");    
    }
};
</script>
```

This helps to remove the spell checker on the Contact field perfectly.

But the spell check on the Check In comments is still popping up like this:
[image]

Comment: this issue is resolved for me. As there was one more user field on my form, I had to apply the attribute to this field as well. and it worked.! cheers